# Best way to add a set of fields in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a CRM and I have a button called "Add Record" When they click add Record I need to append the following to my form field:

```
<div class="record">
Record Name: <br /><input name="recordName" type="text" /><br />
Record: <br /><input name="record" type="text" />
</div>
```

They can add any number of "records" that they want.

My question is, what is a good way of doing this where I can collect all the data for an unknown number of these records and submit it via ajax. I know all the ajax stuff, I just know theres an easier way of doing the dynamic fields than what i'm thinking about doing.

Comment: best way is off topic on so... no way is the best ,,,but more good than other

Comment: Could you be more specific about why you would need to loop through to get the data? What data, and could you post a code sample.

Comment: _"that seems difficult because i'd have to do a loop to get all the data"_ - Why is a loop difficult? Why don't just try what you've suggested and see if it works?

Comment: I have edited my response to be more clear...

Comment: `$(template).clone(...).appendTo(container)` tends to be my first choice for adding a complex HTML fragment. Then to gather your data, loop with `.each()` to visit the records in turn, and accumulate total(s) in outer variable(s).

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of how many you have added in javascript then use this 'id'. eg. if you already have one record (record #0) then id would = 1;

```
<div class="record" id="record-1">
  Record Name: <br /><input name="record[1][name]" type="text" /><br />
  Record: <br /><input name="record[1][record]" type="text" />
</div>
```

If you set an id on the div you can remove it in the future if they decide they don't want it.  Or jump to that div if you detect validation errors etc.

When this is sent to php, you can access like,

```
echo $_REQUEST['record'][0]['name'];

foreach($_REQUEST['record'] as $r)
  echo $r['name'];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays for more information.

Comment: Also note the markup is done in html but the processing of the inputs into an array is done on the php side.

Answer (score 0):

using knockoutJS you can achieve this rather easily

```
           var appVM = {
                  records: ko.observableArray(),

                  addRecord: function(){

                      records.push({ recordName:"" })
                  }
           }

           $(function(){
                  ko.applyBindings(appVM);
           });


           <div data-bind="foreach: records">
                <div data-bind="recordName"></div>
           </div>
           <form action="">
                <button data-bind="click: addRecord">Add Record</button>
                <input data-bind="value: records[records.length-1].recordName></input>
                <input type="submit">Save</input>
           </form>
```